# How to disable ActiveRecord query logging while loading fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app, whose tests load a large number of fixtures.

Loading those fixtures generates a very large amount of ActiveRecord SQL logs (one for each INSERT query, including the whole fixture content). Those logs spam the `logs/test.log` file, and makes skimming the logs very inconvenient.

How can I prevent the SQL fixtures logs from spamming the test log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Rails's logging level is now `:debug` for all environments, ActiveRecord SQL queries indeed get logged during tests – including when loading fixtures.

A solution could be to **entirely disable the ActiveRecord SQL logs entirely during tests**. For this, simply setting `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = :info` would be enough.
But then you won't see any SQL log, even during the actual tests. And those logs can be quite convenient, for instance to quickly see which and how many SQL requests are performed.

A finer-grained solution is to **overload `ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures`, to disable SQL logs for this method only**. It can be done by inserting a custom module into `ActiveRecord::FixtureSet`:

```rb
# Add this to the bottom of your tests/test_helper.rb file.

module FixturesLogSilencer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    # Remove fixtures creation queries from test logs, even when config.log_level = :debug
    def create_fixtures(fixtures_directory, fixture_set_names, *args)
      ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence(:info) do
        Rails.benchmark 'Loading fixtures', level: :info do
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::FixtureSet
  prepend FixturesLogSilencer
end
```

(An up-to-date version of this snippet may be found at https://gist.github.com/kemenaran/cfc820487a62e592dfda196903b6e10c)

After this, instead of all the fixtures SQL logs, your `test.log` file just  contain a line like:

```
Loading fixtures… (395ms)
```